# Inclusion vector module conflict c++

Tags: c++, vector, module, inclusion

I have a problem with the inclusion of the vector module. It seems to there is a conflit with others modules. Here is the structure :

In the simulation.h :

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SIMULATION
#define SIMULATION

#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
// #include <vector>

#include "File.h"
...
void afficherResultat(std::vector<Client> sortie);
...
#endif
```

And the File.h file :

```
#pragma once

#ifndef FILE
#define FILE

#include <vector>

class File {
    ...
    std::vector<Client> l;
    ...    
};

#endif
```

And I get 108 errors starting with : C4091 warning and C4430, C2065, C4229 errors...
Some people spotlight the order of the inclusions. Any Ideas ?

Comment: And you're right ! that work ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a macro for an identifier which is part of the standard library:

```
#define FILE
```

(see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Types for what `FILE` is).

Doing so is forbidden and will cause very weird errors.

Instead use names which are as unique as possible as include guards, e.g.  `INCLUDE_GUARD_FILE_H`.

If you have an include guard there is also no need for `#pragma once` which is a non-standard way of solving the double inclusion problem that the include guard is also supposed to prevent.

Additionally you have not declared `Client` in `File.h`. Probably some `#include` for the header file defining `Client` is missing.